# Setting "Security Enabled Access" on SQL Database to "Required" in Azure Management Portal breaks Automated Export

Tags: security, azure, azure-sql-database

I've been running an instance of SQL Azure for a while now and making use of the Automated Export feature to backup directly into Azure Storage.

I've recently switched over to use the Security Enabled Connection String-

```
{server}.database.secure.windows.net
```

-so I could make use of the auditing features in Azure too. I set my Security Enabled Access settings to *Required* to enforce that, as I don't want to miss out on the auditing.

However I've had no new backups in Azure Storage since I switched over. I've investigated into the issue but can't come to a solid conclusion of what's going wrong.

I'm still able to connect to the server and view the database in SQL Management Studio using the non-secure connection string-

```
{server}.database.windows.net
```

-but I can't see any tables in the database, which is good as that indicates that the secure connection is indeed required.

My gut feel is that the automated backup in Azure uses the non-secure connection string by default and hasn't picked up the *Required* Security Enabled Access setting.

The automated backup feature is still in preview mode so the setting may not be supported yet.

**So the question is:**

Does anyone have any links to official resources detailing this limitation and/or has also experienced the same problem and has a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below issue has been fixed. Using SECURITY ENABLED ACCESS required and Import/Export works.

> There is a [known issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/52bb4818-8c8a-42a1-b6be-5b57b82a42af/export-failing-in-both-portals?forum=ssdsgetstarted), which is getting fixed, when using
>   SECURITY ENABLED ACCESS required and import/export. There are a couple
>   of workarounds you can use to get around this.
>
> 1. You can use client tools, like SSMS, and login do your database as the server principal and use the built-in export data-tier application
>      functionality. To do this, login with the secure connection, right
>      click on the database you want to export, select tasks, and select
>      export data-tier application. Make sure you update SSMS with the
>      update to [support V12 servers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx). You can find it [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011055/).
> 2. If you don't need to audit the import/export, you could also set SECURITY ENABLED ACCESS to optional.
>
> I suggest using the first method because you still will audit the
>   operation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now fixed. There should be no problem running automated / manual import / export while having auditing enabled.

Comment: I don't think this was an issue with auditing at all, as you can have SECURITY ENABLED ACCESS set to Required without configuring auditing. Could you provide a link that explains what the fix is?

Comment: @Tomer - MSFT please provide documentation that it is now fixed.